# Don`t Update if the Possible Output is Zero

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a two tables as shown below:

[image: Tables]

The left table is populated with data based on the column `SRNumber` and after that you can see that the Table `stockrequisition` and Table `generalinventory` have the same data in the column `ItemCode` and `Qty` (`RequestedQty` on the left table)

**mySQL Command**

```
UPDATE GeneralInventory AS tb1 
INNER JOIN StockRequisition AS tb2  
ON (tb1.ItemCode= tb2.ItemCode) 
SET tb1.Qty = Format(tb1.Qty - tb2.RequestedQty,2) 
WHERE tb2.SRNumber = 'SR487SHL'
```

and that command is located at the button <kbd>Update</kbd> where the code works

**Code Output**

`GeneralInventory.Qty` = `GeneralInventory.Qty` - `StockRequisition.RequestedQty` where `StockRequisition.SRNumber` = `SR487SHL` and `GeneralInventory.ItemCode` = `StockRequisition.ItemCode`

**Issue**

How can I determine if the output of `GeneralInventory.Qty` becomes negative so that I can stop the update command. something like this

```
    if the future output of GeneralInventory.Qty < 0 or Negative then
        Msg("Unable to update your request because some of Items Qty will result to Negative,Please review it first")
else
'Do the Update Command
End If
```

Here is my whole code in VB.Net

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    one()
    two()
End Sub
Private Sub one()
    Dim con1 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password=admin1950;database=inventory")
    Dim sql1 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("select SRNumber,ItemCode,RequestedQty from stockrequisition where SRNumber = 'SR487SHL'", con1)
    Dim ds1 As DataSet = New DataSet
    Dim adapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
    con1.Open()
    adapter1.SelectCommand = sql1
    adapter1.Fill(ds1, "MyTable")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)
    con1.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub two()
    Dim con1 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password=admin1950;database=inventory")
    Dim sql1 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("select ItemCode,Qty from generalinventory", con1)
    Dim ds1 As DataSet = New DataSet
    Dim adapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
    con1.Open()
    adapter1.SelectCommand = sql1
    adapter1.Fill(ds1, "MyTable")
    DataGridView2.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)
    con1.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con1 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;database=inventory;userid=root;password=admin1950")
    Dim cmdinsert As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("UPDATE GeneralInventory AS tb1 INNER JOIN StockRequisition AS tb2  ON (tb1.ItemCode= tb2.ItemCode) SET tb1.Qty = Format(tb1.Qty - tb2.RequestedQty,2)WHERE tb2.SRNumber = 'SR487SHL' AND tb1.Qty >= tb2.RequestedQty", con1)
    con1.Open()
    cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con1.Close()
    one()
    two()
End Sub
```

I hope you get me, TYSM for future help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `CASE WHEN`:

```
UPDATE GeneralInventory AS tb1 
INNER JOIN StockRequisition AS tb2  
ON (tb1.ItemCode= tb2.ItemCode) 
SET tb1.Qty = CASE WHEN tb1.Qty - tb2.RequestedQty < 0 THEN tb1.Qty THEN Format(tb1.Qty - tb2.RequestedQty,2) END
WHERE tb2.SRNumber = 'SR487SHL'
```

Or you can use `IF`:

```
UPDATE GeneralInventory AS tb1 
INNER JOIN StockRequisition AS tb2  
ON (tb1.ItemCode= tb2.ItemCode) 
SET tb1.Qty = IF(tb1.Qty - tb2.RequestedQty < 0, tb1.Qty, Format(tb1.Qty - tb2.RequestedQty,2))
WHERE tb2.SRNumber = 'SR487SHL'
```

Or you can do it like this:

```
UPDATE GeneralInventory AS tb1 
INNER JOIN StockRequisition AS tb2  
ON (tb1.ItemCode= tb2.ItemCode) 
SET tb1.Qty = Format(tb1.Qty - tb2.RequestedQty,2)
WHERE tb2.SRNumber = 'SR487SHL'
AND tb1.Qty >= tb2.RequestedQty
```

If you want to return messsage, then you have to create a procedure.

Comment: Sir I want something that The system will give me a Msg that the Whole Transaction will not be update because there are some items that will become negative if the update will continue but anyway sir TYSM.

Comment: @NyxAssasin Then you should create a procedure, I think.

Comment: The code that worked for me is the 3rd one but I want some message on this

Comment: I am using VB.Net Sir I can update my code for you, Wait for a minute

Comment: Please see the Edited Post

Comment: You have to do this row by row if you want to return message for negative row.

Comment: That`s what Im thinking but I need to create a future computation for this like column1 - column2 something like that

Comment: What do you mean about *a future computation*?

Comment: I will Extract the Qty from the GeneralInventory and Minus it in RequestedQty before updatating it check it in each row

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that all you need is an extra WHERE clause

Format(tb1.Qty - tb2.RequestedQty,2) >=0

Comment: Sir I want something that The system will give me a Msg that the Whole Transaction will not be update because there are some items that will become negative if the update will continue but anyway sir TYSM.